# try to connect ssh on VM ubuntu 18

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04, gcloud

I try to connect VM on ssh got Permission denied (publickey) so i try on cloudshell and try to make key on vm still got same problem

```
[enter code here][1]to set key and update metadata when i put `ssh [instance name] [zone] [project id]
```

still Permission denied (publickey)

what should i do next try to open port 22 still same problem even log on serial port all so got login problem loop

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

and add

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

problem still the same can login or connect ssh

try to make new key to ssh key on console and make startup-script `#! /bin/bash
useradd -G sudo username
echo 'username:password.' | chpasswd

## !/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/ufw allow 22/tcp`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj8Kp.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFc0Y.jpg)

Comment: For me the problem is here " sbin/ufw " ubuntu firewall may be messing witt the ports (ip tables) or something in your instance, Can you share to us the output of this command ' nmap [EXT_IP] ' ?

Comment: Also please share to us the complete error message you are getting from the console by connecting to it via gcloud command and adding --log-http flag at the end of the command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh avoiding sharing PII

Comment: i didi it and still chack_b@cloudshell:~ (a4dwork)$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create --network=NETWORK           \
>         default-allow-ssh --allow=tcp:22
Creating firewall...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/a4dwork/global/firewalls/default-allow-ssh' already exists
chack_b@cloudshell:~ (a4dwork)$ sbin/ufw
-bash: sbin/ufw: No such file or directory
chack_b@cloudshell:~ (a4dwork)$

Comment: @Jujosiga I cant use code  namp. it's show command not found

Comment: You may need to install it first, you can do the nmap from any machine you have https://nmap.org/ this will ensure us if the issue is inside your VM instance or in the GCP configuration like SSH keys or Firewall rules.